# Ping - Bad value for option -s, valid range is from 1 to 4

Tags: java, command-line, solaris, ping

I have java code in which I'm trying to get user input for various parameters like package-size, package-count and other ping parameters that could be passed for ping command like -I, -i, -g etc.
My java code using webservices to invoke or run the command at solaris server.

```
System.out.println(2,"ping " + prefix + " " + ip + " " + packageSize + " " + packageCount);
runSystemCommand("ping " + param + " " + ip + " " + size + " " + count));

public static String runSystemCommand(String command) {
        String s = "", v = "";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            // reading output stream of the command
            while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Trace.out(1, s);
                v += s + "\n";
            }
            return v;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Trace.out(1, "Error: " + e);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

where param, ip, size and count will be taken from java swing form.
On giving the value for these fields in form and passing it like above, eg: param="-s", ip="110.121.23.23", size="40" and count="6" forming the statement `ping -s 110.121.23.23 40 6`. I'm getting the output from server `Bad value for option -s, valid range is from 1 to 4.`
Whereas executing the above statement give expected output.

Also executing command like this :
`runSystemCommand("ping -s " + ip + " 40 6"));` works, but here there's no other parameters passed and things are constant pretty much

Comment: `ping -s 110.121.23.23 40 6` is not a valid ping statement. When trying to execute it locally here i get the expected error `ping: invalid packet size: "110.121.23.23"`. The value for the option -s (packet size) should directly follow the -s statement, otherwise how is the program supposed to know which of the numbers is intended as packet size. So you ping command with pacet size 40 and count of 6 should be `ping -s 40 -c 6 110.121.23.23`

Comment: Maybe you should put the `-s` option symbol just before the option's value, like `-s 40`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS as I mentioned, the same ping -s 110.121.23.23 40 6 works if executed directly on the solaris server but this doesn't work if executed via java program.

Answer (score 2):

The issue resolved cause I was running the code in my local setup which is windows and the command ping -s IP 40 6 gives error but the application is meant to run on Solaris server and on building the application and running it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is deprecated. You should use `ProcessBuilder` to execute process from code.

```
public static String runSystemCommand(String... command) {
    String s = "", v = "";
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        
        while (true) {
            s = r.readLine();
            if (s == null) { break; }
            v += s;
        }
        
        return v;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Trace.out(1, "Error: " + e);
    }
    return v; 
}
```

and call this by

```
runSystemCommand("ping", "-s", ".....", . . . . );
```

Tested this [here](https://ideone.com/DNWYLP)

Comment: `Runtime.exec()` is not deprecated. Deprecated has a specific meaning in Java, that it is explicitly documented as such and marked with `@Deprecated`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes my bad, I didn't mean `@Deprecated` in technical terms, I use it if I have to use single-word commands quickly. Rather for multi-argument commands I prefer this.

Comment: I dont know will this really solved the issue that the same command works on server and if passed via program doesn't.
one more thing if passed something like this "ping -s "+ip+" 40 6" it worked.

Comment: @Korbax Did you try?

Comment: @bradley101 yes i tried, same issue